# How to call a top level function that has the same name as variable in Dart?

Tags: dart

Simplified code example:

```
int value() => 1;
main() {
  int value = value(); // Error here: 'value' isn't a function 
}
```

Is there a way to specify that I want to call a function?

If no, why is it impossible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use an import prefix

```
import 'this_file.dart' as foo;

int value() => 1;
main() {
  int value = foo.value(); // Error here: 'value' isn't a function 
}
```

Comment: This is a clever work-around. An alternative is to add a private forwarder: `int _value() => value();` at the top-level and call that instead. The Dart scope rules always pick the closest enclosing declaration, and it shadows all other declarations with the same name. For instance methods you can write `this.foo()`, for static methods you can write `ClassName.foo()`, but for top-level methods there isn't a simple thing you can write, no scope override that picks the top-level scope, except the clever import shown here, but inside the same library you can add the forwarder if necessary.